# nested try, catch and async, await requests

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch, fetch-api

I'm trying to make three requests using fetch(), each one depends on the results of the previous request.  If any of the requests fail, I want to throw a custom error.

This pattern works except if the innermost request fails, it throws all three errors.  If the middle request fails, it throws the middle and outer errors.

How can I fix this so it only throws the error from the level where the request fails?  Is there a better way to write this?

```js
async function requests() {
  try {
    let response1 = await fetch();
    if (response1.ok) {
      try {
        let response2 = await fetch();
        if (response2.ok) {
          try {
            let response3 = await fetch();
            if (response3.ok) {
              let jsonResponse3 = response3.json();
              return jsonResponse3;
            }
            throw new Error('Request 3 failed');
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
        throw new Error('Request 2 failed');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    throw new Error('Request 1 failed');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to throw an error and not continue, don't catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```js
function dummyFetch() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                ok: true
            })
        }, 500)
    })
}

async function doAllSteps() {
    const response1 = await dummyFetch()
    if (!response1.ok) {
        throw new Error('foo')
    }

    const response2 = await dummyFetch()
    if (!response2.ok) {
        throw new Error('foo')
    }

    const response3 = await dummyFetch()
    if (!response3.ok) {
        throw new Error('foo')
    }

    const response4 = await dummyFetch()
    if (!response4.ok) {
        throw new Error('foo')
    }

    return 'you did it!'
}

function go() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(doAllSteps())
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}

go().then((success) => {
    console.log(success)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you do them one after another instead of nested?

```
async function requests() {
    try {
        let response1 = await fetch();
        throw new Error('Request 1 failed');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (response1 && response1.ok) {
        try {
            let response2 = await fetch();
            throw new Error('Request 2 failed');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    if (response2 && response2.ok) {
        try {
            let response3 = await fetch();
            throw new Error('Request 3 failed');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    if (response3 && response3.ok) {
        let jsonResponse3 = response3.json();
        return jsonResponse3;
    }
}
```